# Python Link Puller

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

So I have successfully used this python script:

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://conceled:conceled@traveler.pha.phila.gov:8443/servlet/traveler')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_key('href'):
        print link['href']
```

To pull Links off website. It works for almost any other website, but when trying the above (the one i need to work, I get a slew of errors:)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joe\Desktop\PHA\AndroidPhones\androidphonescript2.py", line 5, in <module>
    status, response = http.request('https://conceled@traveler.pha.phila.gov:8443/servlet/traveler')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib2.py", line 608, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cacheFullPath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib2.py", line 449, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib2.py", line 427, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1157, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site has an invalid certificate, but that doesn't seem to be causing a problem. What version of httplib2 are you using? I just installed the current version, 0.7.7 and I'm getting better exception text:

> File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.7.7-py2.7.egg\httplib2__init__.py", line 1287, in _conn_request
>       raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
>   ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at conceled:conceled@traveler.pha.phila.gov

So it's not parsing `//username:password@` as the username and password. [Httplib2 documentation](http://httplib2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#examples) indicates credentials should be provided via:

```
Http.add_credentials(name, password[, domain=None])
```

So try:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http.add_credentials(name, password)
status, response = http.request('https://traveler.pha.phila.gov:8443/servlet/traveler')
```

I don't have an account on the site so I can't test.

If you need to be able to support username and password in the URL, you'll have to write code to parse it out yourself. Shouldn't be too hard with a regex (Python re module).

Comment: Worked Great! Remove the "domain='/servlet'" parameter and it runs fine. And yes i do believe I'm running an outdated version of httplib2, but after making your alterations its running fine.

Comment: Updated my answer to remove `domain='/servlet'` from the `add_credentials` call.